# Как передать index элемента в функцию jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть html код:

```
<li class='li' onclick='myFunction()'>
<li class='li' onclick='myFunction()'>
<li class='li' onclick='myFunction()'>
```

И есть функция:

```
function myFunction() { 
   alert(сюда нужно вывести индекс элемента);
}
```

Нужно получить порядковый номер элемента, на который кликнули. Нужно именно этим способом. Такие варианты прошу не предлагать:

```
$("li").on("click", function(){
    alert($(this).index());   
});
```

Как передать параметр первым способом, чтобы все работало? Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  var all = el.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".li");
  for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    if (all[i] == el) {
      console.log("индекс: " + i);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<li class='li' onclick='myFunction(this)'>One</li>
<li class='li' onclick='myFunction(this)'>Two</li>
<li class='li' onclick='myFunction(this)'>Three</li>
```

Comment: большое спасибо! То, что нужно

Comment: @Victor Пожалуйста. Успехов!